# PrivacyListManager.getInstanceFor is NULL in android aSmack

Tags: android, xmpp

I'm using aSmack library for implementing connection with XMPP server. Connection and chat is working fine. But when I am implementing blocking user using PrivacyManagerList it return NULL.

```
public void blockUser(String listName, String user) {
        // Set the name of the list
        listName = "newList";

        String groupName = "enemies";
        ArrayList privacyItems = new ArrayList();

        PrivacyItem item = new PrivacyItem(PrivacyItem.Type.jid.toString(),
                true, 1);
        item.setValue(user);
        privacyItems.add(item);

        // Get the privacy manager for the current connection.
        PrivacyListManager privacyManager = PrivacyListManager
                .getInstanceFor(connection);
        // Create the new list.
        try {
            privacyManager.createPrivacyList(listName, privacyItems);
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

That's code from documentation, but that doesn't work. PrivacyListManager always null.
Please, i need some help to solve that problem.
Thank you!

Comment: Hi rasulzhan, did you resolved this problem..I am facing this problem and searching for sollution. Kindly help me if you got sollution. Plz

Answer (score 1):

just use
    Class.forName(PrivacyListManager.class.getName());
before
    XMPPConnection.connect();

Comment: Really bad solution. Don't use reflection. It can fail at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
PrivacyListManager privacyManager = new PrivacyListManager(connection);
```

Comment: It is a private constructor.The constructor PrivacyListManager(Connection) is not visible

Comment: Hi AamirAli, kindly help me if you resolved this problem

Comment: @sham.y its not private constructor, kindly update your xmpp library

Comment: AamirAli, thanks for your reply.
I am using latest asmack library. In that it is a private constructor. Please guide me any another way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi Aamir, can you provide me the providermanager code for this. Blocking user code is working fine in java. PrivacylistManager is null only in asmack.